Restricting the solution space of a set of System of Trigonometric Linear Equations?
Given a pair of trigonometric equations of the form:
$\sin x_0 + \sin x_1 + \sin x_2= 1$
$\sin (x_0 + x_1) + \sin (x_1 + x_2) + \sin (x_2 + x_0) = 2$
Three of the solutions of this system are [angles in degrees]: $(x_0, x_1, x_2)$= (90, 0, 0) or (0, 90, 0)  or (0, 0, 90).
Query 1: Are there other solutions of this system $(0 \leq x_i < 360)$?
Query 2: If there are other solutions, can we add more (linear) equations to this system, so that the set of valid solutions are only restricted to the 3 above?

2: Of course we can add equations so that your solution is the only one. Add $\sin(x_0)=0$, $\sin (x_1)=0$ and $\sin(x_2)=1$, for example.

I don't believe that there are. It appears that (up to periodicity by $360^\circ$), the first equation forms what can only be described as a "pillow octahedron" and the second equation forms an "egg", and the two only intersect at the the three points you've described. You can pan and zoom around this 3D rendering and have a look. I've restricted the domains of the two surfaces so you only see just one copy of a repeating tiling of these shapes. In the upper right "wrench" menu, you can click "Translucent surfaces" to see the inside surface better.

@Sammy Black You should transform your excellent approach into an answer.
